# Tools to monitor performance of C# methods

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, visual-studio-addins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)

I am really not sure if such a tool or Addins exits to `monitor` the `performance(time elapsed)` of each `methods/line` of code.

I heard something that a tool will help us for this task which can be attached to VisualStudio. Anyone aware of it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many performance measuring tools for .NET - they are commonly called profilers.

See [DotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) and And [Ants performance profilers](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) - these are commercial products.

Answer (score 3):

ANTS Performance Profiler can report that. It is a commercial product

Answer (score 0):

Our [C# Profiler](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Profilers/CSharpProfiler.html) can do this.  Like others mentioned here, it is a commercial product.